# Date parameter for a @QueryParam + @PathParam

Tags: java, date, jersey, query-string, path-parameter

regarding java jersey
how can i state a @DefaultValue for a Date parameter?

ex.

```
@DefaultValue("?????") @QueryParam("dateCreated") Date dateCreated
```

Also, continuing the question,
how can i leave empty a Date parameter at a URL that is constructed with a @PathParam? 
Demonstration: http://localhost:8080/testcreate/????? so that its empty or null or whatever except specific formated value 
ex.

```
@Path("/testcreate/{date}")
        @GET
        public Response testCreate(@PathParam("date") Date date){}
```